# Cuando ingreso números grandes no continúan los for

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

Soy nueva en *C++* y estoy aprendiendo desde lo básico y practicando acumuladores y creando dos *for* anidados que su ciclo sea solicitar el primer numero del primer *for* luego el segundo numero del segundo *for*, luego el primer número del primer *for* y así hasta que terminen.

No sé porque cuando digito números grandes no concluye en pedirme los 4 valores, pero no entiendo por qué, funciona bien cuando se ingresan valores de 2 y 3 pero si se ingresan valores de 100 y así no funciona, y a veces solicita los 4 valores o sino solo solicita 1 o 2 pero no sé por qué.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    int acumulador1, acumulador2;
    acumulador1=0;
    acumulador2=0;

    for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=2;j++){
            cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :"<<i<<endl;
            cin>>i;
            cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :"<<j<<endl;
            cin>>j;

            acumulador1 = acumulador1+i;
            acumulador2 = acumulador2+j;
        }
    }
    cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 1 es :"<<acumulador1<<endl;
    cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 2 es :"<<acumulador2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estas usando la misma variable para iterar, que la variable que ingresa el usuario.. eso no esta nada pero nada bien... porque entonces tu for se escapa de los rangos cuando ingresas cualquier valor...

Comment: hola te recomiendo que leas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuesta bastante entender tu pregunta, de modo que te comentaré lo que he visto en el código.

La variable `i` la declaras en el `for` exterior con:

```
for(int i=0; i<=2;i++)
```

Luego declaras las variable `j` dentro del `for` interior en:

```
for(int j=0; j<=2;j++)
```

Las variables `i` y `j` son los contadores que utilizas en los ciclos `for`, pero el problema es que luego las modificas dentro del `for` cuando pones las líneas:

```
cin>>i;
```

y

```
cin>>j;
```

De esa forma ya los ciclos `for` no van a hacer la cantidad de iteraciones que tú quieres.

Deberías declarar dos variables locales dentro del `for` interior, por ejemplo, `x` e `y`, y utilizarlas para la entrada de usuario en lugar de `i` y `j`. Más o menos así:

```
for(int i=0; i<=2;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<=2;j++){
        int x, y;
        cout << "Ingrese el primer numero :" << i << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Ingrese el segundo numero :" << j << endl;
        cin >> y;

        acumulador1 += x;
        acumulador2 += y;
    }
}
```

Comment: a ya ya entiendo supongo que ese fue mi error, que en los for adentro es mejor definir otras variables para las entradas de usuario

Comment: Es un pequeño detalle que a veces se nos escapa sin querer. Si crees que la respuesta resuelve tu pregunta, por favor, márcala como aceptada. Que tengas suerte y progreses rápido.

Comment: si muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

estaba analizando tu código y encontré lo siguiente:

`int acumulador1, acumulador2;`

declaramos las variables donde se almacenaran mis acumuladores

`acumulador1=0;acumulador2=0;`

inicializamos los acumuladores

`int valor1, valor2;`

declaramos las variables donde se almacenaran mis datos que voy a digitar, eso te falto colocar

`for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){`

en el primer for -> se va a encargar de interar 3 veces

`for(int j=0; j<=2;j++){`

con el segundo for se va a encargar de iterar 3 veces

`cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero: ";`
`cin>>valor1;`

Ingresamos el primer valor a digitar

`cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero: ";`
`cin>>valor2;`

Ingresamos el segundo valor a digitar

`acumulador1 = acumulador1+valor1;`
`acumulador2 = acumulador2+valor2;`

En las variables acumulador1 y acumulador2 almacenamos los valores digitados en cada iteración que serian 9 veces digitados.

`cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 1 es :"<<acumulador1<<endl;`

`cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 2 es :"<<acumulador2<<endl;`

Al final obtenemos en las variables acumulador el resultado final acumulada.